# Animate crashes Mathematica

Tags: animation

I'm editing my post by giving all the code I have until now. I'd like to write a program which "unravels" randomly and piece by piece a given image. At the moment, I'm using an image randomly created with Image[] (endImage), and I'm starting with a grey background (whitePart and beginImage). I divide the image in partNumber x partNumber parts (here 10):

```
partNumber = 10;
allParts = Flatten[Outer[List, Range[1, partNumber], Range[1, partNumber]], 1];
endImage = ImagePartition[
   Image@RandomReal[1, {400, 400}]
   ,
   400/partNumber];
whitePart = Image@Table[0.5, {400/partNumber}, {400/partNumber}];
beginImage = Table[whitePart, {partNumber}, {partNumber}];
```

(* After that, I create a random ordering of the unraveling of the parts with *)

```
replaceOrdering = RandomSample[allParts];
```

(* Then, a short function which replaces `beginImage` part number `indexNumber` with `endImage` part `indexNumber`: *)

```
replacePartWithNumber[tableOfParts_, indexNumber_] :=
 ReplacePart[tableOfParts,
  replaceOrdering[[indexNumber]] -> 
   endImage[[Apply[Sequence, replaceOrdering[[indexNumber]]]]]]
```

(* Creation of the list with recursion: *)

```
stage[1] = replacePartWithNumber[ beginImage, 1];
stage[n_] := replacePartWithNumber[stage[n - 1], n]
```

(* which finally gives the `Animate` command: *)

```
Animate[
 ImageAssemble@stage[n]
 ,
 {n, 1, Length@replaceOrdering, 1}
 , DefaultDuration -> 10
 , AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

This works for values of `partNumber` till ca. 25. But with `partNumber = 40` or `=50`, Mathematica crashes immediately...

Any idea why this is?
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no way anyone can help you without knowing hoq `sequence` is defined.

Comment: How can we judge if you provide no information on your `sequence`? Your error message does not seem to be memory-related, are the frames generated by a function or is `sequence` an array of images?

Comment: My bad: I'm editing my post right now!

Comment: You start your animation with `n = 0`. Perhaps that's what's wrong...

Comment: @cormullion: even when changing the start of the animation to `n=1`, Mathematica still crashes...

Comment: [works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HkViq.png) :)

Comment: @cormullion: with which value of n ?

Comment: you mean `partNumber` I suppose. Yes, I managed to crash  it now... :(

Comment: Yes, I indeed meant partNumber... Ok, any idea why it crashes with larger numbers?

Comment: The message from Mathematica (replacing Animate with Table) is "Recursion limit exceeded (1024 or something)", but since I don't really understand recursion I can't see where it goes wrong...

Answer (score 1):

With large values for `partNumber`, I get the message

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

The fix would be to increase `$RecursionLimit`.

```
Animate[Block[{$RecursionLimit = 10000}, ImageAssemble@stage[n]],
 {n, 1, Length@replaceOrdering, 1}, DefaultDuration -> 10, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

There would be no need for this fix, if the recursion were eliminated, like this:

```
stage[n_] := 
 ReplacePart[beginImage, 
  Thread[Take[replaceOrdering, n] -> Extract[endImage, Take[replaceOrdering, n]]]]
```